# Android: Alert Dialog

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog (int id) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);    
        builder.setTitle(R.string.instant_alert_screen_title);
        builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
        ListView aa = new ListView(this);       
        aa.setAdapter( new IconicAdapter());
        aa.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                switch (arg2) {
                case 0:
                ......   
                break;
                case 1:
                ......
                break;
                case 2:
                ......
                break;

        builder.setView(aa);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Done", new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();    
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();    

            }
        });
    return builder.create();
```

Ok guys..I have a `AlertDialog`..In `Adapter` i set to dialog 3 `CheckedTextView`...
How in on Positive Button Listener i could find a second item and check is it checked or not ?

Dont recomend me to do like this:

```
   CheckedTextView a = (CheckedTextView)findViewById(R.id.text)
   boolean b = a.isChecked();
```

I need to use `onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)`  this dialog Interface...is that real ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.  Please consider rewording.

Comment: I was planing to edit your question but I seriously don't know what you are asking there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doyou mean find a second item in the dialog? When you add it to the dialog, save a reference to it and use that reference in your listener. (If it's a local variable, you'll need to declare it `final` to use it in the OnClickListener inner class.) Also, the code you don't want us to recommend might work if you changed it to

```
CheckedTextView a = (CheckedTextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead, it might serve you're purposes a bit better if you don't need additional customization :

```
class ClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int itemSelectedPos) {
        switch(itemSelectedPos) { ... }
    }
}   

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Title...");
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(new String[] { "Item1", "Item2" }, -1, new ClickListener());
```

Also you can replace the string array with your adapter if needed.